# Cannot convert byte to byte[]

Tags: string, byte

I tried to make a function to get a string but didn't actually worked. Please notice I'm not good at c#

```
static byte[] getString(byte testok)
{
   return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(testok);
}
```

What I'm actually trying to do:
https://prnt.sc/uvfs53

Answer (score 0):

You are convert **TO** string, so need the function to return a String. Also - ReadAllBytes returns a byte array (byte[]) not a single byte, so you also need to change that in the parameters. This should work:

```
static String getString(byte[] testok)
{
   return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(testok);
}
```